# regex for links - help to understand it

Tags: regex

how do you read this regex?

```
#(http|https|ftp)://([A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*(?:.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+):?(d+)?/?#i
```

this is a regex for links, but i'm having trouble to understand it

Thanks

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: I'm relatively sure that the `.` should be escaped. As for understanding it: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is a good place to start.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on what language you're in, regexes need a delimiter. Seems the # (pound sign or hash) is used here. So,

```
#...actual regex goes here...#
```

In javascript you need forward slashes (/..../).

Some regex engines allow you to pass flags that influence matching process. These appear after the closing delimiter:

```
#...actual regex goes here...#..flags go here..
```

In your example, there is one flag, the i and I am guessing that means: "case insensitive" (i for insensitive). Depending on the regex engine you can have flags that influence the syntax you can use for the actual regex (for example, the dot can match either any character or any character except newlines depending upon wheter a flag was passed), flags that influence how the matching is done (for example, in javascript a g indicates the global flag, and that means matching anywhere inside the string is done, and state is preserved), flags that determine whether whitespace is allowed as indentation inside the regex. And some have a m flag indicating whether the regex will be applied on a line by line basis, or on the entire text. There is AFAIK no standard set of flags, check your regex engine documentation.

If you have multiple flags, you just concatenate them together to a string of flags and put them after the closing delimiter.

Now for the actual regex. First, you start with a parenthesized expression:

```
(...group...)
```

This is also called a group. In many regex engines, these groups have special meaning, because when a match is found you can access the bits of text that matched the expression inside the group using a special variable (or sometimes, the match is returned as an array, where each element represents a group). If you can access the bits inside groups, it is called a "capturing group".

In this particular case the group uses "alternation" or "choice" and this is indicated by the | (pipe). The pipe is part of the regex syntax and means "or". So,

```
(http|https|ftp)
```

means: match "http", or if that doesn't match, "https", of if that doesn't match, "ftp". This also brings up another reason for using parenthesis: of all special regex syntax operators, the pipe has the lowest precedence, so the parenthesis would not have been there, it would have meant: match "http" or "https" or "ftp://...etc"

So far, we've seen these "special characters": | (pipe) and ( and ). After that we get

```
://
```

These are not special characters, and any non-special characters simply match themselves.

We then get another group, which makes up almost the rest of the regex:

```
([A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*(?:.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+)
```

Inside it, we see a bracketed expression:

```
[A-Z0-9]
```

The brackets [ and ] are special, and indicate a "character class". There are other ways to denote character classes, but in all cases a character class matches a single character. Which character depends on the nature of the class. In this case, the class is defined using two ranges:

```
A-Z
```

means characters A thru Z (and anything in between) and

```
0-9
```

means characters 0 thru 9 (and anything in between).

Basically, [A-Z0-9] matches any alpha-numeric character.
Note that the dash between the boundaries of the range is only a special character inside these bracketed expressions. Paradoxically, a dash inside the brackets can also simply mean a dash if it cannot be interpreted as a range.

This is folllowed by yet another character class:

```
[A-Z0-9_-]
```

Almost the same as the previous on, it just adds the underscore and the dash. This last dash cannot be interpreted as a range separator, so it simply means a dash. This character class will match any alpha-numeric character as well as underscore and dash.

This class is followed by a * (asterisk) and this is a special character indicating a cardinality. Cardinalities specify how often the immediately preceding element may occur. These are the common cardinalities:

- `*` (asterisk) means zero or more times.
- `?` (question mask) means zero or once.
- `+` (plus) means one or more times.

Now the entire bit starts to make sense:

```
[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*
```

means: a sequence starting with one alphanumeric caracter, optionally followed by a string of "word" characters (that is, alphanumeric, dash and underscore).

The following bit of the regex is this:

```
(?:.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+
```

I think this is trying to match the domain parts. So that if you have say:

```
https://mail.google.com
```

The `.google` and `.com` bits would be matched by this part. The initial `(?:` bit is meant to tell the regex engine to not create a "backreference". This is not really my stronghold, maybe someone else can explain. But the rest of that group is quite clear and resembles what we saw before. I think there is a mistake though: the dot (.) that appears immediately before the bracketed character class usually means "match any character" or "match any non-newline character", not "match a literal dot". Typically if you want a literal dot, you need to escape it. This would be the syntax in javascript and I think perl:

```
(\.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+
```

(note the backslash immediately before the dot to indicate a literal dot)

The final bits of the regex seem an attempt to match a port number:

```
:?(d+)?
```

However, the `d+` bit is probably wrong: right now it matches "one or more d's". It should probably be:

```
:?(\d+)?
```

meaning: optionally match a colon (:), optionally followed by a bunch of digits. The `\d` is also a character class, but a predefined one. I think most regex engines use `\d` to denote a digit, but you should check the documentation of your engine to see the exact convention. So in say:

```
http://domain.server.extension:8080/
```

this part of the regex would match :8080 (provided you fix the d+ thing).
Finally, we see

```
/?
```

Meaning the entire thing can be followed optionally by a forward slash.

So, all in all, I don;'t think this matches a "link", rather it matches the inital part of a URL. To match an entire url, you would need a bit more, at least I don't see any expression that could match the path, resource, hash and query bits that may occur in a proper URL.

Comment: @Tim heh, it's been a while since I've been on stackoverflow. I guess that was good for my patience-practicing skills :)

Comment: You deserve the reversal badge.

Comment: +1 Great answer. One small point, your explanation for `:?(d+)?` is wrong. You explained what (I think) it should be, but actually it is: Match an optional colon then a  optional series of the letter "d". I think the "d" should be escaped.

Comment: @stemra: thanks for the kind words. And, you're correct: d+ matches multiple d's. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @Roland Bouman : thanks roland! great answer, it's all clear to me. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

When you say you have trouble understanding it, it means you tried something and are stuck somewhere?

Please ask more specific questions.

I can give you some keywords that you can lookup them more easy, a good place for that is [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)

`(http|https|ftp)` is an alternation

`[A-Z0-9]` is a character class

`*`, `+` and `?` are quantifiers

`(...)` is a (capturing) group, `(?:...)` is a non capturing group

The `#` at the start and end are regex delimiters, the `i` at the very end is a modifier/option (match case independent).

The `(d+)?` at the end would match one or more (optional) letters "d". This is quite strange. I assume it should be `(\d+)?` that would be one or more (optional) digits.